# Perl: Why would eq work, when =~ doesn't?

Tags: perl

Working code:

```
if ( $check1 eq $search_key ...
```

Previous 'buggy' code:

```
if ( $check1 =~ /$search_key/ ...
```

The words (in `$check1` and `$search_key`) should be the same, but why doesn't the 2nd one return true all the time? What is different about these?

`$check1` is acquired through a split. `$search_key` is either inputted before ("word") or at runtime: (`<>`), both are then passed to a subroutine.

A further question would be, can I convert the following with without any hidden problems?

```
if ($category_id eq "subj") {
```

I want to be able to say: `=~ /subj/` so that "subject" would still remain true.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$check1 =~ /$search_key/` doesn't work because any special characters in `$search_key` will be interpreted as a part of the regular expression.

Moreover, this really tests whether `$check1` contains the *substring* `$search_key`. You really wanted `$check1 =~ /^$search_key$/`, although it's still incorrect because of the reason mentioned above.

Better stick with `eq` for exact string comparisons.

Comment: What would a special character be, if as stated, all it is, for example, is: "move"?

Comment: @Jon: well, if you compare against a constant that obviously doesn't contain any special regex characters, it will work. However, when you compare against another variable you don't always know what characters it contains.

Comment: Even if `$search_key` had no special regex characters, `/^$search_key$/` would match either `$search_key` exactly or `$search_key` with a trailing newline character.  Use `\z` when you really mean "end of string."

Comment: @Jon, if `$check1` contains `move` and `$search_key` contains `move`, then `$check1 =~ /$search_key/` will return true. (It will also return true when `$check1` contains `mover`, btw.) Your implication that it doesn't means you don't know what `$check1` or `$search_key` actually contains.

Comment: @ikegami: I believe that is the problem, I played around a lot to get to this point, with splits and s///, so it could be something unseen is there. Thanks a lot for clearing this up everyone.

Answer (score 11):

as mentioned before, special characters in $search_key will be interpreted, to prevent this, use `\Q`: `if ( $check1 =~ /\Q$search_key/)`, which will take he content of `$search_key` as a literal. You can use `\E` to end this `if ( $check1 =~ /\b\Q$search_key\E\b/)` for example.

This information is in  [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters)

Comment: You could also use `quotemeta`:  `my $new_key = quotemeta( $search_key ); if( $check1 =~ /^$new_key$/ )`.  See `perldoc -f quotemeta` for details.

Comment: Well, at the end of the day, what's the point of using `$check1 =~ /\b\Q$search_key\E\b/` when simply `$check1 eq $search_key` would suffice? Looking hackerish?

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev what's wrong with looking hackerish? ;--) Seriously, obviously it's not the same thing as eq, it's an example destined to enlighten the reader. At the end of the day, that's what we're looking for here.

Comment: OK, as an educational experience it's great, but not so as an applied practice.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question, if just you want plain substring matching, you can use the [index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) function. Then replace

`if ($category_id eq "subj") {`

with

`if (0 <= index $category_id,  "subj") {`

This is a case-sensitive match.

Addition for clarafication: it will match `asubj`, `subj`, and even `subjugate`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I've never heard of the index function before, so it gives me some reading to do!